# How to loop and reverse react-native animation

Tags: react-native, animation, expo

In my expo app have an image that i want to use for a loading animation. The animation i want to achieve is an infinite loop of scaling the image bigger, smaller, bigger etc. like a "pulse". I am using react native animation.

I have tried to loop two animations ( one forward and one reverse ) without any luck.

What am i doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
  const scaleValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.loop(Animated.timing(scaleValue, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 800,
      useNativeDriver: true
    }).start(() => {
      Animated.timing(scaleValue, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 800,
      useNativeDriver: true
      })
    }))
  }, []);

  const interpolated = scaleValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 0],
  });

      return (<Animated.Image
        style={[
          {
            width: 165,
            height: 75,
            transform: [{scale: interpolated}],
          },
        ]}
        source={Logo}
      ></Animated.Image>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sequence()](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated#sequence) method.

```js
Animated.loop(
  Animated.sequence([
    Animated.timing(scaleValue, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 800,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }),
    Animated.timing(scaleValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 800,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }),
  ]),
);
```